# Checkbox determine which data is sent to database

Tags: php, html

I have a checkbox that sends the Value "YES" to my database when it is clicked (was the session missed or not?). Depending on whether this checkbox is clicked or not I would like other data to be sent to the database. It would be best if this could be done through an `If` `Else` statement.

Below I have some code that I have tried but it seems as though the data is sent after the form is submitted so it doesn't really work.

```html
<label class="control control--checkbox">Missed Session
  <input type="checkbox" name="missed_session" value="YES" />
  <div class="control__indicator"></div>
</label>

<?php
   $x=(htmlentities($treat['completed_sessions']));
   if(isset($_POST['missed_session'])){
     echo"<input type='hidden' id='completed_sessions' name='completed_sessions' value='print (($x));'>";
   }else{
     echo "<input type='hidden' id='completed_sessions' name='completed_sessions' value='print (($x+1));'>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: You're generating different inputs for a the form, based on the form you have received... it will not work ;) Instead of this you can either implement a similar logic in javascript ('if the checkbox changes, then change also this form field...') or in php, when you receive the values of the form (eg. 'if I receive this parameter, then I save this in the database,,,'')

Answer (score 0):

I try to do most of my verification on the server side. You can have an if statement that will check for `$_POST['missed_sessions']` and alter `$x` before it is inserted/updated in the database.

```
  $x = (htmlentities($treat['completed_sessions']));
  if (!isset($_POST['missed_session'])) {
    $x += 1; // add one to 'completed_sessions'
  }
```

This code would typically be used in an update/insert function like so:

```
  function updateData() {
    if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {
      $id = $_POST['id'];
      $user = $_SESSION['username'];
      $x = (htmlentities($treat['completed_sessions']));
      if (!isset($_POST['missed_session'])) {
        $x += 1; // x now is increased by one before db entry
      }
      $stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE sessions_table SET
        user = '$user',
        x = '$x'
        WHERE id = '$id'");
      $stmt->execute();
      // more code, etc.
    }
  }
```